# How to update an Access database at a particular time in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, timer

I would like to update an Access database at a particular time.

For example:

I have a startdatetime = 11/08/2011 8:00 AM.

I want to update the database when `DateTime.Now = Startdatetime.AddMinutes(30)`

How do i do this in Vb.net?

I thought about using a Timer, but i am not sure how to update the database when the timer stops.

Note: This statement will be in a loop, because I will be updating e.g `For i = 1 to n`

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but i am new to programming, what is backgroundworker?

Answer (score 0):

"I thought about using a Timer, but i am not sure how to update the database when the timer stops."

When the timer expires, you want to take some action. This is a fundamental reason why timers exist. Timers generally fire an event or call a delegate when they elapse. You set the timer up so that its event or delegate will update the database, or call the method that does so. Read the documentation for your preferred timer to find out the details.

Example of an event-based timer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Example of a delegate-based timer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: Thamks, i will check the documentation out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a loop already, it is pretty straightforward:

```
Dim dtLastUpdated As DateTime = DateTime.Now

For i = 1 To n

  ' Test the 
  If DateTime.Now.Subtract(dtLastUpdated).TotalMinutes >= 30 Then
      ' Record the new time
      dtLastUpdated = Date.Now

      ' Update your database
  End If

Next
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have a question reagrding your code. If DateTime.Now.Subtract(dtLastUpdated).TotalMinutes < 30, I want it to wait its = 30 before updating the database. How do i do that? (More like when the time is this, do something)

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't want to do anything else in the loop until the 30 minutes have passed?

Comment: Okay, let me explain better. I have a loop which gets all the rows in a database. And each row has a startDate. so i want to update another database when timenow >= StartDate.Addminutes(30) for each startDate in the row.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. You need to get the StartDate from the database row as a DateTime, then perform your test. For example, If DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartDate).TotalMinutes() >= 30 Then update the database.